# Why does hover work, but not active for my button?

Tags: css, sass

So I'm trying to make a button were if hover it does a cool effect but if you click it, it bobs down a bit.

The problem is, when I use :active, it does not work.
(can't seem to fix the &--transparent part)

If you don't come from SASS, then the & is the route of the class

---

&--transparent,
&--transparent:link,
&--transparent:visited {

```
background-color: transparent;
border: 2px solid $color-white;
position: relative;
transition: all 0.2s;

&::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: $color-white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleX(1.25) scaleY(1.8);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

&:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

&:hover {
  background-color: $color-white;
  color: $color-primary;

  &::before {
    transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

}

---

Comment: please provide a minimum reproducible example: i suggest you use the code snippet tool to show a bit of your html+css combo to help debug the cause of the problem

Comment: Some more code (html,css) would help for answer. Up to this: if your html/sass results at least in `button.class--transparent` hover seems to work: it changes color and background color.